# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT API de Google

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Buenas es la primera vez que estoy usando la API de google maps address. La cuestión es que tengo selectores en los cuales elijo las ciudades por las que quiero filtrar, con eso construyo un arreglo y inicio el mapa, pero se ve que hay un limite de peticiones.

Por más que busco las cosillas que he probado no me funciona ninguna, no se si me podeis arrojar un poco de luz sobre el tema.

Lo máximo que estoy iterando son 21 ubicaciones a la vez.

Uno de los sitios que he buscado soluciones es [aquí](https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/javascript/over-query-limit-en-la-api-de-google-maps-v3-como-detengo-retraso-en-javascript-para-ralentizarlo/1067954200/) pero no hay forma

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initMap() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.4078968, -0.4317228);
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapId: '6d7bc70ff139bf71',
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions);
    codeAddress()
}


function codeAddress() {
    addressArray.forEach(function (item, index, array){
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': item}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(7);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

---

**Prueba según la página que puse**

```
var codeAddress = (function() {
        var index = 0;
        var delay = 200;
        const labels = "C";
        function GeocodeCallback(addressArray, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(addressArray[0].geometry.location);
                new google.maps.Marker({ 
                    map: map, 
                    position: addressArray[0].geometry.location,
                });
                console.log(addressArray);
            }
            else console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        };
    
        return function(vPostCode) {
            if (geocoder) setTimeout(geocoder.geocode.bind(geocoder, { 'address': "'" + addressArray + "'"}, GeocodeCallback), index*delay);
            index++;
        };
    })();
```

Parece que funciona algo mejor, aunque no queda muy bien el echo de que se vayan añadiendo, además que solo coge como 2 ubicaciones, pero tengo varias dudas:

1. En este caso no hay que hacer un foreach
2. No hay forma de esperar a que cargue todo y una vez listo se muestra?
3. Hay otra forma que no sea así que pueda funcionar

Comment: wellcome to the hell, tienes que cachear los datos en una base de datos como firebase ... y si no te responde el api te pegas a lo que ya hayas guardado ... fue lo que tube que hacer con una extension XD

Comment: Hola @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent un placer saludarte de nuevo, me va grande un poco esto voy a investigar

Answer (score 0):

El bucle `forEach` no espera lo que ocurre dentro. Corre de una sola vez, gatillando tus 21 peticiones de una sentada. Para evitar esto la solución tradicional sería ir consumiendo tus direcciones en espera de geocodificación (ej haciendo `pop()` al arreglo) y cada vez que el callback del geocoder responde, decidir si la función se invoca a sí misma con la dirección siguiente o bien (cuando ya no quedan direcciones pendientes) termina el proceso.

Esto, de funcionar, funciona, pero el código es "callback hell". Cognitivamente esa recursión no es intuitiva de leer, te obliga a manejar el estado del arreglo en la función misma o mantener una variable libre en el scope superior, y por último hoy en día hay una solución más fácil: el método  `geocoder.geocode(...)` **es variádico**. Si en vez de pasar un callback como segundo parámetro no le pasas nada, [te devuelve una promesa](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/promises). (sujeto a que uses una versión más o menos reciente)

Entonces, en vez de

```
function codeAddress() {
    addressArray.forEach(item => {
       geocoder.geocode( { 'address': item}, function(results, status) {
         // callback hell y over_query_limit
       })
    });
}
```

Puedes iterar con un bucle `for...of` (que a diferencia del `forEach` sí respeta las promesas) y dentro de éste geocodificar de a uno

```
// La declaro asíncrona para usar await dentro de ella
async function codeAddress() {
  for(let item of addressArray) {
      try {
        let results = await geocoder.geocode({address:item})
        // y luego haces algo con results[0].geometry.location
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn('no se pudo geocodificar',err)
      }
  }
}
```

Esa implementación siempre hará las peticiones de a una. Y fíjate que una geocodificación fallida no se reporta en el callback (que no existe) sino que se maneja como excepción.

Si quisieras paralelizar el proceso para geocodificar, por ejemplo, de 2 en 2, una posibilidad sería armar el array de direcciones como un conjunto de  sub-arreglos de 2 elementos, y en cada bucle usar

```
   await Promise.all([
              geocoder.geocode(...), // dirección 1
              geocoder.geocode(...) // dirección 2
   ])
```

Pero eso ya son refinamientos de la misma idea general: promesas en vez de callbacks.